# In the Io language, how can you see the implementation of "if"?

Tags: reflection, iolanguage

I was poking around some of Core and Object using "getSlot("*method name*") to see how some foundational methods were implemented. I was curious about how the *if* method was written and tried

```
Io> Object getSlot("if")
==> Object_if()
Io> Object getSlot("Object_if()")
==> nil
```

Neither of these were informative. Is there a way to reflect/inspect/print this (and other Object_*keywordishword*() words)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I gave a talk to a group in New York a while back which included a cleanroom implementation of `if` if you're curious about the mechanics. You can see it [here](http://www.slideshare.net/jtregunna/intro-to-io).

More directly, when you see:

`==> Object_if()`

In the REPL, what that's telling you is that `if` is a symbol bound to the object `Object` which is implemented in C. That is to say, the "method" is actually a `CFunction` object, and not a `Block` object. Only `Block` objects show their source in the REPL.

Comment: Wow, I got a reply from the famous Jeremy Tregunna! I'm never again washing or changing the shirt I wore when I read this reply. It's pretty cool that you can see the inner workings of almost all methods right in the REPL--I'm glad to know I can look at the C code if I get really curious about the few that don't show in the REPL.